# How to use promises to wait to export a module

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise, module.exports

Basically I have a few async operations needed in the setup of my express app. I used to include `module.export = app` at the very end of my script, but it wont include the stuff in async functions because they end after that line is reached.

I put a counter called wait which when it equals 0 should mean all the async functions have finished.

I tried putting it into a loop, and an loop inside a promise, but nothings working

```
wait = 1;
()=>{
    //async function
    wait--;
}

module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('hi', wait)
    setInterval(function () {
        if (wait == 0) {
            console.log('everything is done loading');
            resolve(app);
        }

        else console.log('...');
    }, 500);
});
```

It just acts like module.exports was never called.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  This make-up pseudo code has all sorts of things wrong with it, but it's kind of pointless to solve all those problems here as there are likely much better ways to solve your real problem.  For example, you don't poll for completion with `setInterval()`.  Instead, you notify directly from the actual completion callback.  Please let us see your real code and real problem you're trying to solve so we can more properly advise you on how to solve the actual problem.

Comment: The problem is putting module.exports = app at the end makes it finish before the async(mongodb) functions are finished. And putting it in a callback doesn't seem to work because the script just ends and returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do is something like this. this is my index.js file.

```
const app = require('express')();
const stuff1 = async () => {};
const stuff2 = async () => {};
const startServer = async ()=> {};
const init = async () => {
 await stuff1();
 await stuff2();
 // some other async or sync stuffs to do before i start my server
 await startServer();
}

init(); // process will exit if failed.
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to solve the OP's issue of exporting from another module at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to write your code into the other folder then you are exporting, at the same time you are expecting that the the return value should be in the promised way. If it is then might this will help you

```
  //index.js
    async (req, res) => {
    await waitingFunction(req.body)
    then(data => {console.log(data)})
    .catch(error => {console.log(Error)})
}
```

Next you want to make the file from where you need to export the function

```
// export_file.js
exports.waitingFunction = async body => {
 new Promise((res, rej) => {
   // do your stuff if it gives error then return you error as below
   if(err) rej(err)
   else res(result)  // this if not error
  })
}
```

NOTE: This sample of code not real code.Just here I tried to give your answer of your question.